# Signed apk/bundle taking too much of time from my android studio

Tags: android, apk, proguard

I am trying to take singed apk build but generating the build getting too much of time (nearly 30 min)

build.gradle:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

Comment: nothing we can really do for you here, if your pc is slow, consider a build server

Answer (score 0):

Set to false these line if you are not using proguard rule file

minifyEnabled false

shrinkResources false

proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'